# MATLAB obtain vector magnitude matrix

Tags: matlab, vector, magnitude

I have 2 matrices containing 2D data on spatial components of Vx and Vy motion vector components.

How to I easily combine the 2 matrices to obtain the magnitude matrix (sqrt(Vx^2+Vy^2))?

Comment: `sqrt(Vx.^2+Vy.^2)`?

Comment: Works and simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `hypot`:

```
result = hypot(Vx, Vy);
```

According to the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hypot.html),

> `C = hypot(A,B)` returns `sqrt(abs(A).^2+abs(B).^2)` carefully computed to
>       avoid underflow and overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the magnitude of two matrices it is the same procedure as with  scalar values. The only difference is that before the *power* operator you have to put a point (`.`) to differenciate that you don't want to do it in a matrix way, only element by element.

```
M=sqrt(Vx.^2+Vy.^2);
```